# I'm interested in using a laptop battery as an external battery pack for phone

Tags: charging

As title said I'd like to use a laptop battery for my phone as an extender.  One usage would be on a plane where my laptop is too bulky to really use but I could pull the battery out of it and use it to keep my phone battery charged while watching movies and what not.  It seems like I should just need a 7805 voltage regulator either linear or switching.  Has anybody done this or thought to do it, it seems like it should be fairly straightforward?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: The question is has anyone done this and am I correct that it is as simple as I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

Many laptop nowadays supports charging over USB while sleeping/suspended. So you only need a long USB cable, and put your laptop under the seat in front of you in sleep mode. A 1.5m cable is best but 1m would work as well.

Comment: Some airlines don't allow you to keep your laptop in a sleep state, they require you to turn it completely off. That being said, some laptops provide power to at least some USB ports even while the power is off. For example, my old Asus EEEpc 1215N had this feature on it's right side USB ports.

Comment: @onik: Good point. Though frankly, if the airline  prohibited laptops in sleep mode, I doubted that they'd not also prohibit turning on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the point of doing this when then are commercially available solutions. Search using the keywords "mobile power bank". Sure this is an interesting project and you can probably save a couple of bucks, but remember you're traveling in a plane, where you might need to explain to the security officers how your homebrew or "hackish" solution isn't an improvised terror weapon.